# Doubly reducing solution to x power n

Tags: python

I tried to solve a pow(x, n) problem in leetcode

> Implement [pow(*x*, *n*)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/pow/), which calculates *x* raised to the power *n* (xn).
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: 2.00000, 10
> Output: 1024.00000
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: 2.10000, 3
> Output: 9.26100
> ```
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> ```
> Input: 2.00000, -2
> Output: 0.25000
> Explanation: 2-2 = 1/22 = 1/4 = 0.25
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> - -100.0 < *x* < 100.0
> - *n* is a 32-bit signed integer, within the range [−231, 231 − 1]

My solution and TestCase

```
import unittest
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(levelname)s %(message)s")
class Solution(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        """
        :type x: float
        :type n: int
        :rtype: float
        """
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        if n < 0:
            return 1 /self.myPow(x, -n)
        else:
            partial = self.myPow(x, n//2)
            logging.debug(f"partial: {partial}")
            result = partial * partial
            if n % 2 == 1: #odd
                result *= x
            else: #even 
                return result

class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.solution = Solution()

    def test_1(self):
        x = 2
        n = 10
        answer = 1024
        check = self.solution.myPow(x, n)
        self.assertEqual(check, answer)

unittest.main()
```

It report error

```
In [3]: !python 50.powerxn.py                                                                                                     
DEBUG partial: 1
DEBUG partial: None
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_1 (__main__.MyCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "50.powerxn.py", line 32, in test_1
    check = self.solution.myPow(x, n)
  File "50.powerxn.py", line 16, in myPow
    partial = self.myPow(x, n//2)
  File "50.powerxn.py", line 16, in myPow
    partial = self.myPow(x, n//2)
  File "50.powerxn.py", line 18, in myPow
    result = partial * partial
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

I don't understand why partial will get a None value?

Comment: When `n` is odd, you don't return anything, you just assign to `result`.

Comment: This happened because you didn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything in the odd case, you're just assigning

```
result *= x
```

Change it to:

```
if n % 2 == 1: #odd
    return result * x
else: #even 
    return result
```